# Why won't the UIImage change?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I looked trough many resources and none have worked for me. I am trying to get an image to change based on the day of the week. I tested out the calendar method in a playground and it would return the correct expected number. However, I am pretty new to Swift and programming and general and am clueless as to why the imageChange method won't change.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var schedule: UIImageView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    var monday = UIImage(named: "monday")
    var tuesday = UIImage(named: "tuesday")
    var wednesday = UIImage(named: "wednesday")
    var thursday = UIImage(named: "thurday")
    var friday = UIImage(named: "friday")
    var other = UIImage(named:"other")




    func calendar()->Int{
        let todayDate = NSDate()
        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)

        let myComponents = myCalendar?.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: todayDate)
        let weekDay = myComponents?.weekday
        return weekDay!
    }
    func imageChange() {
        if calendar() == 2 {
            schedule.image = monday
        }

        else if calendar() == 3 {
            schedule.image = tuesday
        }

        else if calendar() == 4 {
            schedule.image = wednesday
        }

        else if calendar() == 5 {
            schedule.image = thursday
        }

        else if calendar() == 6 {
            schedule.image = friday
        }

        else if calendar() == 7 {
            schedule.image = other
        }

        else if calendar() == 1 {
            schedule.image = other
        }

        else {
            schedule.image = other
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You're not calling your function?

Comment: Whenever I call my function, I get an error asking for a declaration.

Comment: put imageChange in viewDidLoad() and it will work. Apart from that, you should group your images in an array, starting from sunday to saturday, and ask for the result of calendar()-1 (because the array starts at index 0), so `schedule.image = myImages[ calendar() - 1] ` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your function much shorter and easier:

```
//Add all your images to an array(other two times for saturday and sunday)
//0 = saturday, 1 = sunday, 2 = monday etc
var imageArray = [other, other, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday]

func imageChange() {
    //Call the function only one time. No need to call it each time you test
    var calendarDay = calendar()

    //You want to know which image you need from your array. -1 because an array starts at 0
    var imageIndex = calendarDay - 1

    schedule.image = imageArray[imageIndex]

}
```

To call your function, you have to do it from inside a function. You can't run a function from within the class body only. So for example in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageChange()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be in this code:

```
var monday = UIImage(named: "monday")
var tuesday = UIImage(named: "tuesday")
var wednesday = UIImage(named: "wednesday")
var thursday = UIImage(named: "thurday")
var friday = UIImage(named: "friday")
var other = UIImage(named:"other")
```

You may may have to state the full name of your image. For Example, instead of:

```
var monday = UIImage(named: "monday")
```

Your code might have to be:

```
1) var monday = UIImage(named: "monday.png")

2) var monday = UIImage(named: "monday.jpg")
```

or any other image type. Do this for all the images.

Hope this will help you with your problem.